# Selecting latest date with QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, vector, select

My shapefile contains columns like "Street", "number" and "date".

What I want to do is, to find the latest date (where we have done house services). If we have 2 dates for one house number ("number"), we want to get rid of the older one (this feature should be deleted). I also added a column "duplicates" which shows 1 when we have more then one date for a house number.

Has anyone an idea how to select the latest dates (or how to delete the oldest ones) with the field calculator?

Comment: It looks your information should be scattered in more than one table ... Does it absolutely have to be done using field calculator or any other way is allowed ?

Comment: Indeed, using the right tool would make this simple: sort by ID  and date (descending), then choose the first ID found.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the expression builder in Select by Expression.

Assuming your date is in a date format, try the following:

`"duplicates" = 1 and "date" < to_date(maximum("date","number","number"="number"))`

This should select all features where there is a duplicate and the date is less than the latest one for that house number.

However a faster calculation may be to select only the houses that have the latest date (which will include features where there are no duplicates):

`"date" = to_date(maximum("date","number","number"="number"))`

And then invert the feature selection.

If the above doesn't work as expected try removing the `to_date()` or also wrapping it around `"date"` in the beginning.

The `maximum()` aggregate function used with grouping and filtering arguments in QGIS's expression builder works much like `max()` with `GROUP BY` in SQL. In this case it groups all the records by house number, finds the maximum date *for each house number*, and then goes through the list of features and returns that maximum date for that house number (not the maximum date of all records!)

Please note you have to use `maximum()` in the expression builder and *not* `max()` (which is not an aggregate function).

I have tested this out in QGIS 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using an SQL query in QGIS DB Manager :

You choose Database / Database Manager / Database Manager then Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers you can then try the following query :

```
select max(date),street, number, id from services group by id
```

where `id` is your "house id". if you need geometry of objects you have to add the `geometry` field.

Then you can load this result as a layer in QGIS and save it if necessary.